# $.ajax Jquery API not working on IE8

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery Ajax API. I'm using following code, but am not able to receive the message from server side script. This works perfect on FF and Chrome. I tried google for a solution however no luck.

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: base_url + "user/savePageCSS",
   data: "pageId="+pageid+"&strStyles="+encodeURIComponent(strstyles),
   success: function (msg) {
     if (msg != "0") {
       alert(msg);
     } else {
       alert('Failed to save content');  
     },
   },
   async: false
 });
```

Comment: Warning: Flawed strategy detected: Use of non-async AJAX.

Comment: @pst: Pfft, don't be so sensational. Sometimes synchronous XmlHttpRequest ("AJAX" is a misnomer, thanks) is just right for the job.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra comma after the `else` statement that IE will balk at.  Removing it should fix the issue:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "user/savePageCSS",
    data: "pageId=" + pageid + "&strStyles=" + encodeURIComponent(strstyles),
    success: function(msg) {
        if (msg != "0") {
            alert(msg);
        } else {
            alert('Failed to save content');
        }
    },
    async: false
});
```

Comment: Does it make the call to the server? Is there an exception before or after the ajax call? Can you add an `error` callback to the ajax call to see if that gets hit?

Comment: It worked :) . I was assigning value to a variable which was not declared, before the code above. FF ignored it, but IE stopped execution and no call was made to the server.